# How can I retrieve data from a column based on order of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 columns:

```
index values
  3     20
  2     50
  12    40
  50    1232
```

Now I also have a list of indexes in some order, let's say

```
order=[12,50,3,2]
```

How can I retrieve a values column in an order as in the order list?

As a result I could have a list/numpy array as such:

```
result=[40,1232,20,50]
```

Comment: `df.loc[order,'values']`?

Comment: Depends on whether you have values in `order` not in your 'index' and how you'd want to deal with possibly duplicated values in your 'index'.